# Client certificate with Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have two VMs with IIS that host my application with Azure Application Gateway distributing the traffic. The gateway is configured to offload SSL and everything is working fine.

However, I'd like to use client certificate authentication on one of the paths of the application - on NetScaler (or some other load balancer) I'd simply put serialized client certificate into HTTP Header (X-Client-Cert).

Can I do something similar with Application Gateway?

Comment: pretty sure you cant, but i might be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment thats not possible, but is in the pipeline of product development of the azure product team.